# Duplicate a Query Built with PHP and Mysql but now in Wordpress

Tags: wp-query

Im trying to duplicate a php mysql script i built but to work in Wordpress. My Regular PHP script with mySQL which works and returns results just fine with the following vars was

```
$currLat = "43.653226";
$currLong = "-79.383184";

$blank = "";
$byDistance = "25";


$params = Array($currLat,$currLong,$currLat,$blank,$byDistance);

$sql = $appDb->rawQuery('SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( bLat ) ) * cos( radians( bLong ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( bLat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM business  WHERE business.bLat != ? HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance' , $params);
```

Im having trouble creating the WP_Query with args to do the same in Wordpress?

```
$args = array(
           'post_type' => 'el2business',
           // What else goes here to build the same query as my PHP mySQL Query Above
           // I Have a meta box called bLat in my custom post type
           // I have a meta box called bLong in my custom post type
       );
```

so I can run to get results?

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
       if( $query->have_posts() ){

           while( $query->have_posts() ){
               $query->the_post();

               $string .= '<li>'  . get_the_title() . '</li>';
           }

       }
       wp_reset_postdata();
       return $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seem to fall outside of realm what's "normal" for WP APIs to do.

There are two general approaches to it:

1. Keep it completely in SQL. If you can figure out how to adapt it to WP's schema you can use [`$wpdb->get_results()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) to run arbitrary query, get what you need, and proceed from there.
2. Doing that via `WP_Query` is more challenging since [custom field parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) don't operate with more complex math/logic like that. You would have to use WP's filters to make *changes* to SQL it generates on the fly.

Overall I would say option 2 is something that makes sense to a developer more experienced with WP specific.

If you are comfortable with general PHP and SQL, but not as much with WP then just going to 1 will probably get things done faster for starters.